# Use NVM to install specific nodejs version in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, nvm

When I try to install NVM using gitlab-ci I get the following error message:

**.gitlab-ci.yml file**

```yml
stages:
    - test

Testing:
    tags: 
    - docker 
    stage: test
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    before_script: 
    - apt-get update 
    - apt-get install curl  -y

    # Install Node Version Manager (NVM) so we can change the node version 
    - curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
    - nvm --version
```

Error message:

```sh
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13527  100 13527    0     0  99463      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 99463
=> Downloading nvm as script to '/root/.nvm'
=> Appending nvm source string to /root/.bashrc
=> Appending bash_completion source string to /root/.bashrc
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
$ nvm --version
/bin/bash: line 116: nvm: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

When I try to reload the terminal in gitlab-ci using `exec bash` the gitlab task ends prematurely, and does not run the rest of the script.

How do I use install and use nvm with gitlab-ci ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update the script to load the nvm commands into your terminal. `". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh"`

```yml
    # Install Node Version Manager (NVM) so we can change the node version 
    - curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
    - ". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh"
    - nvm --version
```

Comment: I had to add `--no-use` after `". ~/.nvm/nvm.sh"`, as otherwise, it would stop the job instantly.