# GitLab CI command not found when using docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gitlab

I feel like I have tried everything, and don't understand why commands can't be found in my GitLab CI script.

Here is my script

```
stages:
  - build

build:
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - docker
  script:
    - adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" meteor_install
    - apt update -y
    - apt install curl -y
    - su meteor_install
    - echo $0
    - cd ~
    - ls -alh
    - curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
    - ls -alh
    - source ~/.bashrc
    - cat ~/.bashrc
    - export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
    - nvm install 12.13.1
    - npm i -g meteor
    - meteor --version
    - npm install -g mup
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - meteor npm install
    - cd .deploy
    - mup setup
    - mup deploy
```

Here is the result, whith quite a lot of debugging information

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.5.1 (de104fcd)
  on docker RKp3-YrG
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image ubuntu:20.04 ...
Pulling docker image ubuntu:20.04 ...
Using docker image sha256:ba6acccedd2923aee4c2acc6a23780b14ed4b8a5fa4e14e252a23b846df9b6c1 for ubuntu:20.04 with digest ubuntu@sha256:626ffe58f6e7566e00254b638eb7e0f3b11d4da9675088f4781a50ae288f3322 ...
Preparing environment 00:04
Running on runner-rkp3-yrg-project-10-concurrent-0 via gitlab-runner...
Getting source from Git repository 00:07
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/soxprox/apps/soxprox-code-server/soxprox_code_server_gui/.git/
Checking out 5c925242 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 01:42
Using docker image sha256:ba6acccedd2923aee4c2acc6a23780b14ed4b8a5fa4e14e252a23b846df9b6c1 for ubuntu:20.04 with digest ubuntu@sha256:626ffe58f6e7566e00254b638eb7e0f3b11d4da9675088f4781a50ae288f3322 ...
$ adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" meteor_install
Adding user `meteor_install' ...
Adding new group `meteor_install' (1000) ...
Adding new user `meteor_install' (1000) with group `meteor_install' ...
Creating home directory `/home/meteor_install' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
$ apt update -y
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1335 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [30.1 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [828 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [733 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [177 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [33.4 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [1275 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [33.6 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1108 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1758 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [797 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [21.7 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 Packages [50.8 kB]
Fetched 20.1 MB in 4s (5258 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
$ apt install curl -y
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates krb5-locales libasn1-8-heimdal libbrotli1 libcurl4
  libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1
  libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common
  libnghttp2-14 libpsl5 libroken18-heimdal librtmp1 libsasl2-2
  libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssh-4 libssl1.1
  libwind0-heimdal openssl publicsuffix
Suggested packages:
  krb5-doc krb5-user libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
  | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-otp
  libsasl2-modules-sql
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates curl krb5-locales libasn1-8-heimdal libbrotli1 libcurl4
  libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1
  libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common
  libnghttp2-14 libpsl5 libroken18-heimdal librtmp1 libsasl2-2
  libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssh-4 libssl1.1
  libwind0-heimdal openssl publicsuffix
0 upgraded, 32 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 5447 kB of archives.
After this operation, 16.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssl1.1 amd64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10 [1322 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 openssl amd64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10 [620 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ca-certificates all 20210119~20.04.2 [145 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2 [549 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 krb5-locales all 1.17-6ubuntu4.1 [11.4 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libkrb5support0 amd64 1.17-6ubuntu4.1 [30.9 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libk5crypto3 amd64 1.17-6ubuntu4.1 [79.9 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libkeyutils1 amd64 1.6-6ubuntu1 [10.2 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libkrb5-3 amd64 1.17-6ubuntu4.1 [330 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libgssapi-krb5-2 amd64 1.17-6ubuntu4.1 [121 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libpsl5 amd64 0.21.0-1ubuntu1 [51.5 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 publicsuffix all 20200303.0012-1 [111 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libbrotli1 amd64 1.0.7-6ubuntu0.1 [267 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libroken18-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [41.8 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libasn1-8-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [181 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libheimbase1-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [29.7 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libhcrypto4-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [87.9 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libwind0-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [48.0 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libhx509-5-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [107 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libkrb5-26-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [208 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libheimntlm0-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [15.1 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libgssapi3-heimdal amd64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [96.1 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libsasl2-modules-db amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2 [14.9 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libsasl2-2 amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2 [49.3 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libldap-common all 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8 [16.6 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libldap-2.4-2 amd64 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8 [155 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libnghttp2-14 amd64 1.40.0-1build1 [78.7 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 librtmp1 amd64 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build1 [54.9 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssh-4 amd64 0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2 [170 kB]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcurl4 amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7 [234 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 curl amd64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7 [161 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libsasl2-modules amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2 [49.1 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 5447 kB in 0s (13.6 MB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libssl1.1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 4127 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openssl.
Preparing to unpack .../01-openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openssl (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ca-certificates.
Preparing to unpack .../02-ca-certificates_20210119~20.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates (20210119~20.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsqlite3-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libsqlite3-0_3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package krb5-locales.
Preparing to unpack .../04-krb5-locales_1.17-6ubuntu4.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking krb5-locales (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkrb5support0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libkrb5support0_1.17-6ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkrb5support0:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libk5crypto3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libk5crypto3_1.17-6ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libk5crypto3:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkeyutils1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libkeyutils1_1.6-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkeyutils1:amd64 (1.6-6ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkrb5-3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libkrb5-3_1.17-6ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libgssapi-krb5-2_1.17-6ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpsl5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libpsl5_0.21.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpsl5:amd64 (0.21.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package publicsuffix.
Preparing to unpack .../11-publicsuffix_20200303.0012-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking publicsuffix (20200303.0012-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libbrotli1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libbrotli1_1.0.7-6ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libbrotli1:amd64 (1.0.7-6ubuntu0.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libroken18-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libroken18-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libroken18-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../14-libasn1-8-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libheimbase1-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../16-libhcrypto4-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libwind0-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../17-libwind0-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwind0-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../18-libhx509-5-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../19-libkrb5-26-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../20-libheimntlm0-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../21-libgssapi3-heimdal_7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsasl2-modules-db:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../22-libsasl2-modules-db_2.1.27+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsasl2-2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../23-libsasl2-2_2.1.27+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libldap-common.
Preparing to unpack .../24-libldap-common_2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8_all.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-common (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libldap-2.4-2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../25-libldap-2.4-2_2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnghttp2-14:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../26-libnghttp2-14_1.40.0-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnghttp2-14:amd64 (1.40.0-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package librtmp1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../27-librtmp1_2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libssh-4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../28-libssh-4_0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssh-4:amd64 (0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcurl4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../29-libcurl4_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package curl.
Preparing to unpack .../30-curl_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsasl2-modules:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../31-libsasl2-modules_2.1.27+dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libkeyutils1:amd64 (1.6-6ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libpsl5:amd64 (0.21.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Setting up libbrotli1:amd64 (1.0.7-6ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libnghttp2-14:amd64 (1.40.0-1build1) ...
Setting up krb5-locales (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libldap-common (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8) ...
Setting up libkrb5support0:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up librtmp1:amd64 (2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build1) ...
Setting up libk5crypto3:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.27+dfsg-2) ...
Setting up libroken18-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up openssl (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.10) ...
Setting up publicsuffix (20200303.0012-1) ...
Setting up libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up ca-certificates (20210119~20.04.2) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
128 added, 0 removed; done.
Setting up libwind0-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libssh-4:amd64 (0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64 (7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8) ...
Setting up libcurl4:amd64 (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7) ...
Setting up curl (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20210119~20.04.2) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
$ su meteor_install
$ echo $0
/usr/bin/bash
$ cd ~
$ ls -alh
total 16K
drwx------ 2 root root 4.0K Oct  6 16:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jan  1 12:19 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.1K Dec  5  2019 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  161 Dec  5  2019 .profile
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 15037  100 15037    0     0   157k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  157k
=> Downloading nvm as script to '/root/.nvm'
=> Appending nvm source string to /root/.bashrc
=> Appending bash_completion source string to /root/.bashrc
=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
$ ls -alh
total 20K
drwx------ 1 root root 4.0K Jan  1 12:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.0K Jan  1 12:19 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.3K Jan  1 12:20 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jan  1 12:20 .nvm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  161 Dec  5  2019 .profile
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ cat ~/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize
# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes
if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'
    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
$ export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
$ nvm install 12.13.1
/usr/bin/bash: line 143: nvm: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:05
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: I solved the problem with the help of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64340715/501827

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use NVM to install specific nodejs version in gitlab-ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64340714/use-nvm-to-install-specific-nodejs-version-in-gitlab-ci)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

should work

Comment: That is already in my .bashrc file, if you look at the output, I have run `cat ~/.bashrc` . The NVM install put's it in there and you can see from my script, that after the install I also run `source ~/.bashrc`.