# How to install specific node version using gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: react-native, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

In my implementation gitlab-ci.ymal as follows

```
  stages:
  - lint
  - test
  - android_steps
  - ios_steps

lint:
  tags:
    - mac-osx
  stage: lint
  script:
    - ls -la "/Users/ec2-user/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/"
    - ls -la /Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives
    - rm -rf /Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/20*/
    - ls -la /Users/ec2-user/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives
    - npm -v
    - node -v
    - rm -rf node_modules/*/.git
    - npm install --force
    - npm run lint
    - npm run circular

test:
  tags:
    - mac-osx
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install --force
    - npm run test -- -u --coverage --silent
```

Where do I need to modify this code to install a specific Nodejs version on VM?

Comment: > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64340714/use-nvm-to-install-specific-nodejs-version-in-gitlab-ci this is work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```yaml
image: node:16.16 # or full - 16.16.0
```

See [gitlab-examples/nodejs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/nodejs/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml#L1)